# ServiceStack OrmLite: .Save/SaveAsync generates Duplicate entry on PRIMARY key

Tags: mysql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I was under the impression that the OrmLite Save method did an "upsert", update if record/row exist, otherwise insert.
In the [documentation for ServiceStack OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#save-methods), it says:

> Save and SaveAll will Insert if no record with Id exists, otherwise it Updates.

However, sometimes I get the duplicate entry error:

> Duplicate entry 'PresentationWorker.Presentations.CoreObjectListPresentation-Pres' for key 'presentationproducer.PRIMARY

The POCO has an `Id` property that is `PrimaryKey`

```
[PrimaryKey]
[StringLength(512)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

Also, the database in MySQL has `Id` as the Primary key:

[image]

1. The first thing that looks strange to me is the error message, where it indicates that the value in the PRIMARY field ends with `CoreObjectListPresentation-Pres`, but it does not, it is actually longer than that, the entire value in the Id field is `PresentationWorker.Presentations.CoreObjectListPresentation-PresentationWorkerModule:TED-RYZEN:37576`

The Id prop in the POCO being saved is however the same as already existing in db:

[image]

and db:

[image]

I would like to understand how I can get the error, if it is supposed to do an `Update` if there already is a PRIMARY KEY with the same value? But as I enabled the logging feature, I can see that the SQL query is actually an INSERT, not an UPDATE:

> SQL: INSERT INTO `PresentationProducer`
> (`Id`,`PresentationType`,`ModuleChannelName`,`LastUpdatedTimestamp`)
> VALUES
> (@Id,@PresentationType,@ModuleChannelName,@LastUpdatedTimestamp)
> PARAMS:
> @Id=PresentationWorker.Presentations.CoreObjectListPresentation-PresentationWorkerModule:TED-RYZEN:37576,
> @PresentationType=PresentationWorker.Presentations.CoreObjectListPresentation,
> @ModuleChannelName=PresentationWorkerModule:TED-RYZEN:37576,
> @LastUpdatedTimestamp=2021-11-21 09:09:02

I am considering some form of race condition, but I am not sure how exactly this happens. I tried finding SaveAsync in the source code, but have not found the relevant code for it.

Is there perhaps an improvement for OrmLite to use the `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` approach when Save methods are used for MySQL?

(Using ServiceStack 5.13.1, .NET5, VS2022, MySqlConnector and db is MySQL8)

Comment: there is no natove supprt but a request to implement it , which you can support also look at the comment this seems worth a look https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/35221267-support-upsert-with-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OrmLite has to check if the record exists before it decides whether a `db.Save*` should either insert or update the record. This leaves room for the possibility that if 2 requests tried to concurrently save the same new record at the same there could be a race condition should the first insert occur just after the second requests check.

Typically this is the result of a double posting bug firing off 2+ concurrent requests. Changing it to use explicit `db.Insert*` and `db.Update*` wont help since you'll get the same response with 2+ inserts.

The proper way to handle this is to use the native upsert functionality in each RDBMS which OrmLite doesn't support yet, please [vote for the feature request](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/42397786-please-add-basic-upsert-functionality) to get notified when the feature is implemented.